# Background play stops when device has a passcode

Tags: xcode6, playback, lockscreen

I need help. After using Xcode 6, the background play will stop after playing for 10 seconds when my iPhone is locked. This happens when the device has a passcode on iOS 7 and above. And I use the AVAudioPlayer. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

It works well if the device doesn't have a passcode.